# Lightning/Aura Components: Too many components for aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

Is there any limit on a number of rendered components on a single page\within a single Lightning App? Here is an error message that occurs sometimes when many records are rendered in a Lightning App:

*"Too many components for aura://ComponentController.getComponent(...)"*

So is it a built-in limit on an Aura/Lightning App component instances number? Or is it the framework failing to handle the number of elements of a single component type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per app/cmp there is a 10,000 inner component limit. This number is chosen and enforced by the framework. Source code [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/java/org/auraframework/impl/context/AuraContextImpl.java#L126).

This was introduced to prevent infinite loop situations where a component included itself in markup repeatedly. It's also an attempt to prevent scenarios that would be detrimental to performance for the app, such as a large number nested loops creating the same or similar component.

Comment: The limit on applies to components that are created on the server, take a look at my answer to my own related question for details http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/135487/16839